# Unity devide prefab

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a Prefab like this (example)

[image]

When Instantiating 'MyPrefab', of course it creates A, B, C as well.

but due to optimization issue, I want to make only with A or B or C like this

[image]

and then, append A or B or C later when it is needed.

Easy solution might just divide MyPrefab with A, B, C.

But the problem is that they have all been deeply linked with each other.

For example, Prefab 'MyPrefab' has a component or script of 'A'...

look forward to your help

[image]

Comment: Maybe you should have to program your prefab more modular-style? So your prefab A is independant from B and C, so you can add it later, building 3 different prefabs, A, B and C, but if they are modular, you can attach them later without problems.

Comment: re-programing might be the only solution... thanks Lotan you saved me a lot